# Construct a McRouter instance in Hack

Tags: memcached, hacklang

I am new to hacklang and I am experimenting and trying to connect to Memcached which is running on my local machine .I am following the official documentation [here](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/asynchronous-operations/extensions) where its advised that we use McRouter class in HHVM stdlib to connect to the Memcached instance.

My code looks very similar to what is their in the documentation

```
private static function createMemcacheConnection(): void {
        $servers = Vector {"127.0.0.1:11211"};
        MemcacheConnector::$mcRouter = \MCRouter::createSimple($servers);
    }
```

When I run this piece of code , I get this error **\nFatal error: Uncaught Error: Class undefined: MCRouter** . I tried to see if there is a separate library that I need to add to my composer , that does not seem to be the case. What am I doing wrong ?